# Let's Encrypt. Certificate all subdomains automaticly. (*.domain.de)

Tags: ssl, encryption, subdomain, wildcard

I want to secure all my subdomains, without creating a subdomain on itself and then create a certificate.

I'm using .htaccess to redirect a subdomain to a folder. So a subdomain is not created on itself. It's just a nameholder to replace a folder.

My problem is: when I want in Plesk to create a *.domain.de subdomain and want to secure it with Let's Encrypt, then I got a error message: "Securing wildcard domains is not supported. Please deselect this option to proceed."

---

QUESTION:

Is there any other way to secure all subdomains automaticly wihtout creating a single cretificate for it?

I though the answer is simple. You would be a BIG help :)

thank you

Answer (score 2):

AND

I answered my question on myself :D thank you for your votes for ym first question.

---

(1) I followed these simple steps:

https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000490174-How-to-install-wildcard-certificates-with-Let-s-Encrypt-

(2) Created a *.domain subdomain via Plesk

(3) Opened the "Hosting Settings" for this subdomain in Plesk

(4) Under the point "Security" choose a certificate

(5) Save the new settings

---

NOW IT WORKS!

---

Hope I helped a lot of you.

---

You are a great community!